# capacitor push notification for android is not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I followed  this official link
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase

but it works for ios, not for android can anyone tell me why. I got this error with the chrome remote device inspect

[image]

ionic info details
[image]

Answer (score 1):

change requestPermission to requestPermissions